# Python - Scipy error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, pip

I was trying to install Scipy and I could not get it to install and I don't want to install a Python package with extra things in. I'm trying to create an AI but at the moment I need this program but I cant get it.

```
pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
 Downloading scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz (13.1MB)
100% |################################| 13.1MB 75kB/s
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\setup.py:366: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 152, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 18, in run
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 148, in run
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 663, in get_mathlib_info
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link
    self._check_compiler()
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 51, in _check_compiler
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 199, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 85, in _get_vc_env
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\setup.py", line 391, in <module>
    # higher up in this file.
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\setup.py", line 383, in setup_package
    if "--force" in sys.argv:
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1064, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
    raise
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\setup.py", line 391, in <module>
    # higher up in this file.
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\setup.py", line 383, in setup_package
    if "--force" in sys.argv:
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uzpsmb90\numpy-1.12.0rc2\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ddiq6h4g\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ddiq6h4g\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 640, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 670, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 850, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1078, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\users\kai\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1066, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in       
C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ddiq6h4g\scipy\

You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'     
command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's different on Linux but compiling python packages can be very difficult on windows (there are a lot of SO questions asking about the dreadful `vcvarsall.bat`).

My advice/workaround: Unless you *really* want to build it, leave the compiling to professionals, and find already compiled wheels for windows, example [on this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). I installed all complex packages like this and it worked fine at first try.

Once you get the file (for instance) `scipy‑0.18.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl` from that page, just do

```
pip install \path\to\downloads\on\your\pc\scipy‑0.18.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
```